# "Please refrain from creating a Parse project inside another Parse project."

Tags: parse-platform, command, line

Beginning with Cloud Code and Parse. Using [this](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#cloud_code/unix).

How do I remove all Parse projects in order to begin creating a new one? I get the following error:

"Would you like to create a new app, or add Cloud Code to an existing app?
Type "(n)ew" or "(e)xisting": e
1:  Test
Select an App to add to config: 2
Detected that you are already inside a Parse project.
Please refrain from creating a Parse project inside another Parse project."

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me.

Open Terminal
Go inside the project folder and type the below command
"ls -a"

Should see two file.
1. .parse.local
2. .parse.project

Remove them by typing in the below command.
"rm .parse.local"
"rm .parse.project"

And then you can execute
"parse new" to create new parse project.

Comment: If you trashed the cloud code directory you previously created, you need to restore it then remove these files, then create a new directory, then you can remove the old one.

Answer (score 1):

You ask two different type of question...

Q1. How do I remove all Parse projects in order to begin creating a new one?

you not remove project from terminal.

if you want remove project, you can remove from parse site...

```
1. https://www.parse.com/apps
2. go to project settings (what ever project you want to delete)
3. brlow show DeleteApp option, fill password and Dilete This App.
```

Q2. Detected that you are already inside a Parse project. Please refrain from creating a Parse project inside another Parse project."

it show because you are alerady in Directory

so, use this command in terminal  cd ..
 after that you can creat New App or use Exist App...

Answer (score 1):

When you create Cloud Code directory, a **config** subdirectory is also created.
There is a **global.json** file in that directory which contains appID and masterkey, until it is deleted you will get the "Please refrain from creating a Parse project inside another Parse project." error. 
If you want to reset the directory (may be change to another app) delete the config directory so that directory and global.json are cleared.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks